# Pandas DataFrame from Dictionary with Lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have an API that returns a single row of data as a Python dictionary. Most of the keys have a single value, but some of the keys have values that are lists (or even lists-of-lists or lists-of-dictionaries).

When I throw the dictionary into pd.DataFrame to try to convert it to a pandas DataFrame, it throws a "Arrays must be the same length" error. This is because it cannot process the keys which have multiple values (i.e. the keys which have values of lists).

How do I get pandas to treat the lists as 'single values'?

As a hypothetical example:

```
data = { 'building': 'White House', 'DC?': True,
         'occupants': ['Barack', 'Michelle', 'Sasha', 'Malia'] }
```

I want to turn it into a DataFrame like this:

```
ix   building         DC?      occupants
0    'White House'    True     ['Barack', 'Michelle', 'Sasha', 'Malia']
```

Comment: do you know beforehand the structure of the data coming in?

Comment: In general, yes. In the hypothetical example, the 'building' will always be a single string, and the 'DC?' will always be a single boolean. But the length of the 'occupants' list may change depending on the building that is queried. Does that answer your question?

Comment: correct, so i was thinking, create a blank dataframe first and then keep adding rows to it. however, note that as Andy points out, this may be ineffcient

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works if you pass a list (of rows):

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[11]:
    DC?     building occupants
0  True  White House    Barack
1  True  White House  Michelle
2  True  White House     Sasha
3  True  White House     Malia

In [12]: pd.DataFrame([data])
Out[12]:
    DC?     building                         occupants
0  True  White House  [Barack, Michelle, Sasha, Malia]
```

Comment: This solution also works with lists-of-lists and lists-of-dictionaries. `data = { 'building': 'White House', 'DC?': True, 'occupants': ['Barack', 'Michelle', 'Sasha', 'Malia'] , 'list_of_lists': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], 'list_of_dicts': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]}`

Comment: It did not work for me where I have 3 lists of the same length for each dictionary key.```nutrients_totals_dict = {
    "Name" : cnf_nutrient_names_all,
    "Value": ["0" for i in range(num_values)],
    "Units": cnf_nutrient_units_all
}```

Answer (score 6):

This turns out to be very trivial in the end

```
data = { 'building': 'White House', 'DC?': True, 'occupants': ['Barack', 'Michelle', 'Sasha', 'Malia'] }
df = pandas.DataFrame([data])
print df
```

Which results in:

```
    DC?     building                         occupants
0  True  White House  [Barack, Michelle, Sasha, Malia]
```

Comment: This works for python 3.x. The pandas from_dict behaviour seems to have changed.

Comment: Hi @ChinmayKanchi, what if there are more than one lines of such data, eg. like 2nd house with another list of [names x multiple] ?

Answer (score 2):

Solution to make dataframe from dictionary of lists where keys become a sorted index and column names are provided. Good for creating dataframes from scraped html tables.

```
d = { 'B':[10,11], 'A':[20,21] }
df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(),columns=['C1','C2'],index=d.keys()).sort_index()
df

    C1  C2
A   20  21
B   10  11
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be acceptable if instead of having one entry with a list of occupants, you had individual entries for each occupant? If so you could just do

```
n = len(data['occupants'])
for key, val in data.items():
    if key != 'occupants':
        data[key] = n*[val]
```

EDIT: Actually, I'm getting this behavior in pandas (i.e. just with `pd.DataFrame(data)`) even without this pre-processing. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had a closely related problem, but my data structure was a multi-level dictionary with lists in the second level dictionary:

```
result = {'hamster': {'confidence': 1, 'ids': ['id1', 'id2']},
          'zombie': {'confidence': 1, 'ids': ['id3']}}
```

When importing this with `pd.DataFrame([result])`, I end up with columns named `hamster` and `zombie`. The (for me) correct import would be to have these as row titles, and `confidence` and `ids` as column titles. To achieve this, I used `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
In [42]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient="index")
Out[42]:
         confidence         ids
hamster           1  [id1, id2]
zombie            1       [id3]
```

This works for me with python 3.8 + pandas 1.2.3.

Answer (score -1):

if you know the keys of the dictionary beforehand, why not first create an empty data frame and then keep adding rows?

Comment: This is not very efficient as pandas creates a new copy for every insertion (so building up a DataFrame in this way is O(n^2) in number of rows).