# How to dictionary inside a pandas column into separate columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

everyone.
This problem has already been asked by others.
[Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns)

I have already asked this question. But it doesn't be resolved.
[How to use pandas to build a column which are in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633940/how-to-use-pandas-to-build-a-column-which-are-in-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment112724600_63633940)

Now, I have a dataframe. It looks like this.

```
                     intron_id                                            octamer
0       >ENSG00000183943.1  AGCCATGC:1 AGUAGCUG:1 GCCUGGCC:1 AGAUGAUG:1 AG...
1       >ENSG00000183943.2  CATATTTC:1 UCCCAAAA:1 AAGCCATA:1 TATTTTGC:1 TA...
2       >ENSG00000183943.3  AGUAGCUG:4 UCAACAGG:1 CCUUUCAU:1 UACCUUUU:1 GC...
3       >ENSG00000183943.4  AUGAGCAC:1 UCCUACGG:1 GGAGGATC:1 AUAGGGUG:1 CC...
4       >ENSG00000183943.5  UUGCCAAU:1 AUGCUGGG:1 ACUAUUUU:1 GGAGGATC:3 UG...
```

Now, I want to transform it as this.

```
    intron_id   AGCCATGA AGUAGCUG  GCCUGGCC ......
>ENSG00000183943.1  1      1         1
>ENSG00000183943.2  0      0        0
>ENSG00000183943.3   0      0         0
```

But when I tried to use apply(pd.Series) or df.octamer.values.tolist() , both of them don't work. I am confused. Hope you can give me some advices. Thank you in advance. My code is as follows.

```
    import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('~/10genomic/elife/octamer/intron_seq/count.txt',delimiter='\t',header=None)
df.rename(columns={0:"intron_id",1:"octamer"},inplace=True)
df['octamer']=df['octamer'].apply(lambda x:str(x))
print(df)


                 intron_id                                            octamer
0       >ENSG00000183943.1  AGCCATGC:1 AGUAGCUG:1 GCCUGGCC:1 AGAUGAUG:1 AG...
1       >ENSG00000183943.2  CATATTTC:1 UCCCAAAA:1 AAGCCATA:1 TATTTTGC:1 TA...
2       >ENSG00000183943.3  AGUAGCUG:4 UCAACAGG:1 CCUUUCAU:1 UACCUUUU:1 GC...
3       >ENSG00000183943.4  AUGAGCAC:1 UCCUACGG:1 GGAGGATC:1 AUAGGGUG:1 CC...
4       >ENSG00000183943.5  UUGCCAAU:1 AUGCUGGG:1 ACUAUUUU:1 GGAGGATC:3 UG...

df.drop(labels=[2370,3967,5728,11875,14464],axis=0,inplace=True)


def builddict(x):
    dictls=[]
    for item in x.split(" "):
        dictls.append(item.split(":"))
    return(dict(dictls))

df['octamer']=df['octamer'].apply(builddict)
print(df)


                intron_id                                            octamer
0       >ENSG00000183943.1  {'AGCCATGC': '1', 'AGUAGCUG': '1', 'GCCUGGCC':...
1       >ENSG00000183943.2  {'CATATTTC': '1', 'UCCCAAAA': '1', 'AAGCCATA':...
2       >ENSG00000183943.3  {'AGUAGCUG': '4', 'UCAACAGG': '1', 'CCUUUCAU':...
3       >ENSG00000183943.4  {'AUGAGCAC': '1', 'UCCUACGG': '1', 'GGAGGATC':...
4       >ENSG00000183943.5  {'UUGCCAAU': '1', 'AUGCUGGG': '1', 'ACUAUUUU':...

print(df['octamer'].apply(pd.Series))


                                                      0
0      {'AGCCATGC': '1', 'AGUAGCUG': '1', 'GCCUGGCC':...
1      {'CATATTTC': '1', 'UCCCAAAA': '1', 'AAGCCATA':...
2      {'AGUAGCUG': '4', 'UCAACAGG': '1', 'CCUUUCAU':...
3      {'AUGAGCAC': '1', 'UCCUACGG': '1', 'GGAGGATC':...
4      {'UUGCCAAU': '1', 'AUGCUGGG': '1', 'ACUAUUUU':...
```

When I tried to solve it as follow, it produced this wrong. I really confuesd.

```
    df=pd.read_csv('~/10genomic/elife/octamer/intron_seq/countdict.txt',delimiter=',',index_col=0)
df=df.iloc[:3,:]
print(df)
            intron_id                                            octamer
0  >ENSG00000183943.1  {'AGCCATGC': '1', 'AGUAGCUG': '1', 'GCCUGGCC':...
1  >ENSG00000183943.2  {'CATATTTC': '1', 'UCCCAAAA': '1', 'AAGCCATA':...
2  >ENSG00000183943.3  {'AGUAGCUG': '4', 'UCAACAGG': '1', 'CCUUUCAU':...

temp_df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.pop("octamer"))
print(temp_df)
0     1     2     3     4     5      ... 73895 73896 73897 73898 73899 73900
0     {     '     A     G     C     C  ...  None  None  None  None  None  None
1     {     '     C     A     T     A  ...  None  None  None  None  None  None
2     {     '     A     G     U     A  ...     :           '     1     '     }
```

Comment: Please provide sample data from count.txt so we can test.

Comment: What is your intended result?

Comment: I have already change this question. Hope you can give me some advice. Thank you!@Mike67

Comment: I have already change this question. Hope you can give me some advice. Thank you ! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 0):

What you might try to do is loop through both columns and create separate dictionaries. This solution isn't the most efficient, but I think it will get the job done.

I would create a dictionary of lists of all the keys:

```
dict = {'intron_id':[], 'AGCCATGC':[], etc..}
```

Then loop through each row of the df and also loop through the dictionary:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dict['intron_id'].append(row['intron_id'])
    for key, value in row['octamer'].iteritems():
        dict[key].append(value)
```

Then recreate the dataframe with the dictionaries.
[Pandas DataFrame from Dictionary with Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504424/pandas-dataframe-from-dictionary-with-lists)

That should do the job. There might be some syntax issues, but hopefully that'll help you out.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I would try your solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ruiyanhou Okay, let me know how it goes. I am curious to see if this works. If it doesn't, I am happy to help you out. If it does work, could you mark it as correct? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First some fake data:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "intron_id": ["A", "B"],
    "octamer": [{'AGCCATGC': '1', 'AGUAGCUG': '1'}, {'CATATTTC': '1', 'UCCCAAAA': '1'}],
})

print(df)
```

[image]

Then extract the column containing the dicts and pass it to [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to create our new dataframe

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.pop("octamer"))
print(temp_df)
```

[image]

Finally merge our original dataframe with our new one, using indices as the keys

```
df = df.merge(temp_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df)
```

Et voilà! (at least I think this is what you wanted anyway)
[image]

**Edit**
I get similarly garbled results if my values are really just strings that look like dictionaries. You can confirm this by extracting a single value from your column and checking its type:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/10genomic/elife/octamer/intron_seq/countdict.txt',delimiter=',',index_col=0)
df = df.iloc[:3,:]
first_octamer = df["octamer"][0]
print(type(first_octamer))
```

I suspect you will see `<class 'str'>` as the result. If so, we can use [ast.literal_eval](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/7436/evaluating-a-string-containing-a-python-literal-with-ast-literal-eval) to try to parse the strings as actual dictionaries:

```
temp_df = df.pop("octamer")
temp_df = temp_df.apply(ast.literal_eval)
temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(temp_df)

df = df.merge(temp_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df)
```

I hope your strings are well-formatted though, else things might get tricky...

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when I tried your method. It doesn't work on my data. My process is shown in the last answer. I don't know where the problem is. Hope to get your help!

Comment: thanks for your help! But when I tried your method, it does not work for my data. Hope to get your answer! The process is in the last of my question!